# How long should a heat pump last before needing repairs?

Tags: hvac, electric-motor

We have a Goodman heatpump Model: SSZ140601 Model Desc.: 14 SEER HP, 5 TON Mfg Date: 6/3/2010

First of all, we did not register the unit so that cut our warranty in half.  Two weeks ago, our compressor motor went out and we had it replaced.  Now, our air handler motor (not sure if I am saying that right) went out.

I thought heat pumps were suppose to last 12 to 15 years.  I am very disappointed in this system.

Is this normal?

Comment: Welcome to DIY! We're glad to have you! This site operates differently from a forum, so don't miss out on the tour, it'll help you understand how to use this site. As for this question, please edit your subject line to be a short, concise question. This site is a bit more formal than a forum, so please edit your question body to state a clear question, and provide relevant background information. Generally, the intention is for this question to be helpful to other people with a similar problem.

Comment: Do you perform the manufacturer's recommended maintenance?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the NAHB](http://stevesmallman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/NAHB-Lifetimes.pdf), the average lifespan of heat pumps in the US is about 16 years.

A Google search seems to reveal a wide range of opinions about Goodman heat pumps in particular.